# How to push down the h1 tag or How to set the position of h1 tag so it appears below my nav bar

Tags: html, css

i'm trying to push down this h1 to go below my navigation tag.
The way i've structured it is that there's header tag, inside the header tag theres a container tag, inside the container tag is the h1 tag, after the h1 tag theres a nav tag with a ul inside the nav tag and a li inside the ul.

```css
.container {
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}


/* Header */

header {
  height: 100vh;
}

header h1 {}


/* An unordered list is basically an array of items*/

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: right;
  /* Top bottom right left*/
  /* Margin-top pushes it down.*/
}


/* List item specifies how it should be aka 1 item of the array */

li {
  display: inline-block;
  /* Top bottom right left*/
}


/* A means all the links */

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: black;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  /* Seperates them*/
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Random Number Generator</h1>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li class="active"><a href="#Home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#About">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Just add the `h1` below `nav`?

Answer (score 0):

Add `h1` below the `nav`

```
 <div class="container"> 
   <nav> 
      <ul> 
         <li class="active"><a href="#Home">Home</a></li> 
         <li><a href="#About">About</a></li> 
         <li><a href="#Contact">Contact</a></li> 
       </ul> 
   </nav> 
   <h1>Random Number Generator</h1>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Moving the `<h1>` tag below your `<nav>` element will move the header element below the navigation element in the DOM (document object model).

```css
.container {
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}


/* Header */

header {
  height: 100vh;
}

header h1 {}


/* An unordered list is basically an array of items*/

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: right;
  /* Top bottom right left*/
  /* Margin-top pushes it down.*/
}


/* List item specifies how it should be aka 1 item of the array */

li {
  display: inline-block;
  /* Top bottom right left*/
}


/* A means all the links */

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: black;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  /* Seperates them*/
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li class="active"><a href="#Home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#About">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <h1>Random Number Generator</h1>
</div>
```